# Python: Parsing HTML elements based on absolute XPath

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, absolute

I'm working on a project where I have to parse 20 different HTML pages based on URLs and I would like to get some information from all of them. Pages have different structure and the required information is on a different place on each site.

I thought I could give Python lxml module a try. Since information can be found on different places on each site and I'm quite lazy to put together 20 * X different reg. expressions, I thought it would be a good idea to use absolute XPaths for these elements. In this way I could simply utilize Copy XPath functionality of Chrome browser and give clear path for each HTML element to my parser and I don't need to code a lot.

I couldn't find any example which shows me how can I refer to an HTML element with absolute XPath in Python. Some of the comments say instead of absolute path it's better to use relative, but don't really explain why. But again, to refer to an element with its relative XPath means some coding work again.

Just to make it more complicated these 20 sites are unicode.

Is there a way to refer to an HTML element with absolute XPath in Python and get back its text value like this?

```
/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/b
```

...and it would give back the text value of the HTML element.

So far I got the following code which works well with relative XPath but when I'm using absolute it gives me the error below.

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit


response = urllib2.urlopen('http://oneofthesites.com')
content = response.read()
doc = UnicodeDammit(content, is_html=True)
parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding=doc.original_encoding)
root = html.document_fromstring(content, parser=parser)
data = root.find('/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b').text_content()
print(data)
```

and the error is:

```
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element
```

Maybe my basic concept is wrong so any other idea regarding how can I process these pages is welcome!

Thanks for your help in advance,
g0m3z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `html.document_fromstring()`; this returns an `Element`, not a `ElementTree` object. Absolute paths are only supported on the latter type.

You have two options:

- Use `html.parse(response)` (note, not the result of `response.read()`); this returns a proper tree object.
- Use a relative XPath expression. Simply replace `/html` with `.`; the top level element is after all the `<html>` tag, the rest is relative to that element:

  ```
  data = root.find('./body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b').text_content()
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and making me clear the difference between `Element` and `ElementTree` Pieters! I tried the second option and replaced `/html` with `.` as you suggested, but now I'm getting the following error from the interpreter: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text_content'`. I'm using Copy Xpath function of my browser so I'm sure that the element exists on the page.  What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Gomez: The expression didn't match anything. Try sub-expressions first, spot where the error lies.

Comment: @Pieters: It fails quite at the beginning of the tree structure. The last expression which works fine is `./body/div[1]/table`. After this it's getting me a `None` result. I checked on the site and the next element would be `tbody` as it's in the XPath expression above. Any idea how can I debug further? Thanks!

Comment: `tbody` is probably added by the browser (it is implied) but not in the physical document. Remove it from the expression and move on.

Comment: I did accept your answer. Is there any other `HTML` element like `tbody` that I need to take care of?

Comment: @Gomez: I think `tbody` is the most common one to be added; `body` and `html` being the others if not present.